# How to add random values in an object array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, random, javascript-objects

```
const prod = [{
    name: "Sweat",
    description: " collection",
    price: 150,

  },
  {
    name: "Trousers",
    description: "Attire",
    price: 243
  },
  {
    name: "T-shirt",
    description: "Winter",
  },
  {
    name: "Hoody",
    description: "Fashion",
  },
  {
    name: "Pants",
    description: "Winter",

  },
  {
    name: "Casual",
    description: "Winter",
    price: 245,
  },
  {
    name: "Shirt",
    description: "Attire",
    price: 150,
  }
];
```

Hi, I'm trying to add a random popularity score between 0 - 100, randomly for the products without them using a function.

I've tried to figure out solutions from

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-data-structure-in-javascript-62e65908a0e6

and

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/getting-a-random-item-from-an-array-43e7e18e8796

but still unsure how to add elements to specific indices without the 'popularity' element. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Filter the array to the elements you want first, then apply the random number

```js
// function
const addRandomPopularityWhereThereIsNone = products => {
  products.filter(p => !p.hasOwnProperty('popularity')).forEach(p => {
    p.popularity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  })
}

// call it
addRandomPopularityWhereThereIsNone(products)
```

Note that this modifies the original array.

For reference:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Object.protytype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I'll give it a try, how would that look as a function as well?

Comment: @PabloJr.Villasenor I don't quite understand what you're asking

Comment: My bad, the problem I'm doing has given me limitations such as creating a function called "addPopularity(products)" and was wondering how to filter that array in a function, thanks!

Comment: @PabloJr.Villasenor well, you'd just wrap the code in my answer in a function. I've updated it with an example

Comment: Thanks Phil! Much appreciated for the extra resources youve psoted as well, will have further research into that as well!

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution

```js
const products = [{"name":"Pullover Sweat","description":"Winter collection","price":150,"popularity":99},{"name":"Formal Trousers","description":"Attire for men","price":500},{"name":"Winter T-shirt","description":"Winter collection","price":50,"popularity":50},{"name":"New Fashion Hoody","description":"Fashion line","price":200},{"name":"Winter Pants","description":"Winter collection","price":150},{"name":"Casual Coat","description":"Winter collection","price":245,"popularity":78},{"name":"Fine Long Sleeve Shirt","description":"Attire for men","price":150,"popularity":10}];

const output = products.map((product) => {
  if ("popularity" in product) {
    return { ...product };
  }

  return { ...product, popularity: generateRandomNumber() };
});

function generateRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

console.log(output);
```

Take a look to [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Comment: I always appreciate an answer that doesn't mutate the source data +1

Comment: I had not noticed the edition, I thought I had done something wrong and I overwritten it, your comment makes sense, I do not know how to apply the edition again

Comment: No probs. I usually just open the console and run `JSON.stringify(dataFromTheQuestion)` and copy / paste it into the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `map` and `nullish coalescing operator (??)`

```js
const products = [{"name":"Pullover Sweat","description":"Winter collection","price":150,"popularity":99},{"name":"Formal Trousers","description":"Attire for men","price":500},{"name":"Winter T-shirt","description":"Winter collection","price":50,"popularity":50},{"name":"New Fashion Hoody","description":"Fashion line","price":200},{"name":"Winter Pants","description":"Winter collection","price":150},{"name":"Casual Coat","description":"Winter collection","price":245,"popularity":78},{"name":"Fine Long Sleeve Shirt","description":"Attire for men","price":150,"popularity":10}];

const update = (arr) =>
  arr.map(({ popularity, ...product }) => ({
    popularity: popularity ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1,
    ...product,
  }));


console.log(update(products));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const products = [{
    name: "Pullover Sweat",
    description: "Winter collection",
    price: 150,
    popularity: 99
  },
  {
    name: "Formal Trousers",
    description: "Attire for men",
    price: 500
  },
  {
    name: "Winter T-shirt",
    description: "Winter collection",
    price: 50,
    popularity: 50
  },
  {
    name: "New Fashion Hoody",
    description: "Fashion line",
    price: 200
  },
  {
    name: "Winter Pants",
    description: "Winter collection",
    price: 150
  },
  {
    name: "Casual Coat",
    description: "Winter collection",
    price: 245,
    popularity: 78
  },
  {
    name: "Fine Long Sleeve Shirt",
    description: "Attire for men",
    price: 150,
    popularity: 10
  }
];


const addPopularity = products => {
  products.filter(p => !p.popularity).map(p => {
    p.popularity = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  })
  return products;
}

console.log(addPopularity(products));
```